# Сохранение файла pptx в pdf при помощи VBA

Tags: vba, макросы, макрос, powerpoint

Добрый день. При автоматизации сложного процесса столкнулся со следующей проблемой, сейчас вкратце её опишу.
Есть файл pptm, в нем макрос, который должен открывать другой файл pptx, обновлять линки(связи) и сохранять его в pdf. Небольшая загвоздка в том, что экспортировать нужно не все слайды, а, например, только 5. Не получается сохранить файл. Не пойму, в чем дело. Помогите, плз. Подскажите макрос, который сохраняет только первые 5 слайдов в pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался!!

В Prs указываете свою презу. Путь к ней и имя. В sss указывается путь к новому pdf файлу.

Dim Prs As Presentation 'Презентация

Dim ar() As Variant

Dim sss as String 'Путь к новому файлу pdf.

sss = "C\Users\www.pdf"

ar = Array()

ReDim ar(1 To 50) 'Указывается диапазон слайдов

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 50

ar(i) = i

Next i

ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate

Prs.Slides.Range(ar).Select

Prs.ExportAsFixedFormat Path:=sss, FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypePDF, RangeType:=ppPrintSelection